# Is it possible to make a mobile website work as a native app in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, single-page-application

I saw using IPhone or Android, it is possible to add a website to the desktop or start screen and this will make this website work as a native app which will open without the browser frame.

Is that possible using Windows Phone and how?

Comment: at the end of this video http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159 at 1:10

Comment: I believe Amr ElGarhy is talking about the "Add to home screen" feature of iOS. It takes the [icon specifed in a <link rel> tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), for the "App" icon, and will open in Safari, but without the frame.

Comment: @AmrElGarhy Just for clarity's sake, it's still just a website. I mean it still needs an Internet connection to load the page.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can pin a website to your howe screen but htis will open in Interenet Explorer when launched